# How to get rid of HTTPS with a proxy?

Tags: networking, proxy, https, squid, privoxy

I am running a tiny private network that consists of a Linux server and some very old computers running very old operating systems like Windows 95 and DOS. The Linux server is running squid and privoxy and allows me to access the modern web with these old machines. My main problem is that the browsers are incapable of handling HTTPS.

Because I am the only one having physical access to this network and I am not doing anything that is in need of being encrypted on these machines, I want privoxy, squid or any other software that might do the job to receive HTTP requests for sites that explicitly only allow HTTPS, get the requested site via HTTPS and then deliver it to one of the old machines over plain, unencrypted HTTP.

Is there anything I could do without having to implement my own anti-HTTPS proxy? Because that's what I would consequently have to do. Not being able to get simple sites like Wikipedia on these machines kinda sucks.

Thank all of you in advance!